# Most optimal way to traverse this array?

Tags: arrays, sorting, groovy

I got this array:

```
[
  [TYPE: house, NAME: john],
  [TYPE: apartment, NAME: bob],
  [TYPE: condo, NAME: jack],
  [TYPE: bungalo, NAME: jill],
  [TYPE: box, NAME: tim]
]
```

And I need NAME where TYPE is condo...but its not a map or dictionary which this probably should have been, so optimally, do I have to iterate over each element and check if TYPE = condo, to get the NAME I want?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you have an unsorted, sequential collection, you need to iterate. Not that it really matters for a five-element collection.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not indexed data, yes, you need to traverse the list to find out what you want:

```
def array = [
  [TYPE: house, NAME: john],
  [TYPE: apartment, NAME: bob],
  [TYPE: condo, NAME: jack],
  [TYPE: bungalo, NAME: jill],
  [TYPE: box, NAME: tim]
]

def result = array.find { it.TYPE == condo }
if (result) {
  println "Found condo: $result"
} else {
  println 'No condo'
}
```

If you are going to do lots of lookups like this, you may want to index  the data once first, then lookups will be much more efficient:

```
def indexedData = array.groupBy { it.TYPE }

// now it's very efficient to find the condo
// but it may have more than one so the values are Lists
def theCondo = indexedData[condo]

if (theCondo) {
  println "The condo again: ${theCondo.first()}"
} else {
  println 'No condo yet'
}
```

[DEMO](https://onecompiler.com/groovy/3y64b7w5x)